# no response from ajax in when method

Tags: jquery, ajax

i have no response after call ajax method in $.when:

```
$.when(tht.ajax.getUserDrp()).done(function (data) {
    if(data)  console.log('hava data')
    else  console.log('no data')
});
```

getUserDrp function:

```
getUserDrp: function(){
  $.ajax({
    url: "../account/getLevel" ,
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (data) {
       // do somthing
    }
  });
}
```

as a result always print 'no data' in console, why?

Comment: what is the data value inside your success function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to use `getUserDrp` as a promise but you don't return the `$.ajax` function result, that's why `.done()` never gets called.

Try:

```js
getUserDrp: function(){
  return $.ajax({
    url: "../account/getLevel" ,
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To use when, done, you need to change your function as follows

```
getUserDrp: function(){
  return $.ajax({
    url: "../account/getLevel" ,
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
  });
}
```

You could also use a callback instead

```
getUserDrp: function(callback){
  $.ajax({
    url: "../account/getLevel" ,
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (data) {
       callback(data)
    }
  });
}

getUserDrp(function(data){
if(data)  console.log('hava data')
    else  console.log('no data')
})
```

Comment: tnx for your answer but I need to know why my code doesn't work correctly!

Comment: That's not really nice of yours copying someone elses answer to the question just to get your points boosted, dude.

Comment: Ha, didn't copy your answer we actually wrote them at the same time! Best to always judge favorably. All the best!

Comment: @ykay Sorry about it then.